# One download at a time with Struts2

Tags: java, struts2

I have a Struts2 Action that uses a [StreamResult](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/stream-result.html) to stream a file. The file is a report that can be very large. I want to set a flag to restrict the user to one download at a time. In my Action, I can set the flag, but I do not have a place to unset it when the stream is finished.

Before Struts, I would set the flag, write to the Servlet's OutputStream, and then unset the flag. But with Struts, the Action just sets the stream to a variable and then the Action is finished. Struts (as set up in struts.xml) then does the sending in a place outside of my control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should create an interceptor that wraps this download action, and it can lock/unlock access for the current user.  See http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/interceptors.html for more information.

Comment: +1 this is probably the easiest. Another way would be to create a custom result type. But if you think about it, it really isn't a good idea because your action would have all ready done the work and then it would expect to render the view (return the stream) but will not be able to do so, or it will have to wait... all in all better to return quickly possibly with an appropriate error message.

Comment: What do you mean, the action would have already done the work? You can check before the action starts if the user has the lock, then you don't execute the action at all.

Comment: "Another way would" ... everything I said after that pertained to if someone tried to implement the solution as a custom result type not as an interceptor.

Answer (score 1):

try override `close` function in class `FileInputStream`, here is the doc for [FileInputStream API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html), if you are using another kind of "inputstream", you just extend it and override the `close` method.

try this code:

```
public class YourInputStream extends FileInputStream {
    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException{
        super.close();
        // here unset your flag
    }
}
```

in your action class:

```
inputStream = new YourInputStream(new File(path));
```